# Google Drive API Resumable Upload PUT request failing. Status Code: 400. Message: Not Found

Tags: rest, google-api, google-drive-api, retool

I'm currently attempting to create an upload system that takes local files and uploads them to google drive.  This is being done through Retool.  My `PUT` query is coming back fine with the needed URI, but my `POST` is failing.  I've been unable to identify the cause after a good amount of research.

Here is the error message i'm receiving (Thrown through JSON formatter for readability):

```json
{
   "data":{
      "statusCode":400,
      "error":"Bad Request",
      "message":"{\"message\":\"Not Found\"}",
      "data":{
         "message":"Not Found"
      },
      "metadata":{
         "request":{
            "url":"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?key=---sanitized---%26uploadType%3Dresumable%26upload_id%3D---sanitized---",
            "method":"PUT",
            "body":"UEsDBBQACAgIAHNbzlIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAeGw...", //base64 string.
            "headers":{
               "User-Agent":"Retool/2.0 (+https://docs.tryretool.com/docs/apis)",
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding":"base64",
               "Content-Length":535487,
               "Authorization":"---sanitized---",
               "X-Retool-Forwarded-For":"104.129.199.15"
            }
         },
         "headers":{
            "x-guploader-uploadid":[
               "--READACTED--"
            ],
            "vary":[
               "Origin, X-Origin"
            ],
            "content-type":[
               "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "content-length":[
               "9"
            ],
            "date":[
               "Fri, 10 Sep 2021 01:58:07 GMT"
            ],
            "server":[
               "UploadServer"
            ],
            "alt-svc":[
               "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
            ]
         },
         "status":404,
         "statusText":"Not Found"
      }
   },
   "errorData":"Not Found",
   "displayOptions":{
      "hideToast":false
   },
   "trigger":"NATURAL_FAILURE"
}
```

The URI matches the URI recorded from `PUT_QUERY.headers.location[0]` perfectly.  My API key is valid, I even decoded the base64 string back to an excel document to double check it was getting corrupted, and I've run out of idea on what could be causing this.

Here are the scopes i've given to the Oauth2 Token being used:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly
```

In case it helps, my `POST` requests looks like..

```json
{
   "request":{
      "url":"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?key=--sanitized--&uploadType=resumable",
      "method":"POST",
      "body":"{"name":"03 Mar 21 Conv--sanitized--.xlsx","parents":"[1NJ--sanitized--ka5W4Zz9Tc]"}",
      "headers":{
         "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
         "User-Agent":"Retool/2.0 (+https://docs.tryretool.com/docs/apis)",
         "Authorization":"Bearer ---sanitized---",
         "X-Content-Length":535487,
         "X-Upload-Content-Type":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: drop the parents part see 400 implies to me that it cant find something.

Comment: For some reason, my insertion of the URI was being URL encoded.  This was causing the API call to send a bad link.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.  Something about how the url substring was being appended was creating a bad link.  Changed code to only pull out the upload_id and now it’s working.  Another error with this code that I hope might help someone else out is that the google drive api resumable `PUT` needs a `Content-Encoding` header, not a `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.  Otherwise the upload will go through, and retain all its metadata (name, directory, etc) and size, but will not open correctly.